# Cannot acces this.myvar in extjs

Tags: javascript, variables, extjs

I am dynamically adding extra columns to a ExtJs grid, so I store the index as a class variable. 
But this does seem to work as shown below. Why is this?

```
for ( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
var column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
    text : names[i],
    header : names[i],
    width : 80,
    dIndx: i,
    renderer: function (val, p, record) {
        var value = record.data.values[this.dIndx];  // doesn't work
        var value = record.data.values[p.column.dIndx];  // this works
    return value ? value : "";
    }
    });
 // add column to grid etc.
```

Comment: `this` is set as the renderer function within that function, use `scope` on your column definition to define `this` for the renderer.

Comment: One other trick to save a few characters -- Your return statement can be `return value || ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `this` is the scope of the <s>controller</s> `Ext.grid.Panel` (if not defined otherwise, see edit) that is why it wan't work by using the keyword. anyway the second is the better solution IMO

**Edit**:

As commented by @kevhender a [scope](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-scope) can be defined for the renderer. But as you are using one of the arguments this makes no sense. Anyway I missed to mention it.

**Edit 2 - why is the default scope `Ext.grid.Panel`**:

Here's a snipped from the function that process the rendering. The Method is private and therefore not listed in the API. Anyway here's the [source link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Table3.html#Ext-view-Table-method-renderCell). Note that the renderer get called with either a given scope or the scope of the owner container `column.renderer.call(column.scope || me.ownerCt,//...` the owner of a view is the panel where it is nested into.

```
/**
 * @private
 * Emits the HTML representing a single grid cell into the passed output stream (which is an array of strings).
 *
 * @param {Ext.grid.column.Column} column The column definition for which to render a cell.
 * @param {Number} recordIndex The row index (zero based within the {@link #store}) for which to render the cell.
 * @param {Number} columnIndex The column index (zero based) for which to render the cell.
 * @param {String[]} out The output stream into which the HTML strings are appended.
 */
renderCell: function(column, record, recordIndex, columnIndex, out) {
    //... more code
    if (column.renderer && column.renderer.call) {
        value = column.renderer.call(column.scope || me.ownerCt, fieldValue, cellValues, record, recordIndex, columnIndex, me.dataSource, me);
        if (cellValues.css) {
            // This warning attribute is used by the compat layer
            // TODO: remove when compat layer becomes deprecated
            record.cssWarning = true;
            cellValues.tdCls += ' ' + cellValues.css;
            delete cellValues.css;
        }
    }
    // ... more code
```

Comment: Good answer! Why this refers to the Panel and not the column?